# Controling 5V relay with Wemos D1 R1

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, wifi, relay, web-server

I would like to control a 5V relay with Wemos D1 R1 module through webserver. I'm using the following modules:

- Tongling 5vdc Relay
- Wemos D1 R1

I'm using the following schematic:
[image: Sketch]

and here is the code I'm using:

```js
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "Myssidname";
const char* password = "Myssidpass";

int ledPin = D3;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 delay(10);


 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

 // Connect to WiFi network
 Serial.println();
 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Connecting to ");
 Serial.println(ssid);

 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
   delay(500);
   Serial.print(".");
 }
 Serial.println("");
 Serial.println("WiFi connected");

 // Start the server
 server.begin();
 Serial.println("Server started");

 // Print the IP address
 Serial.print("Use this URL : ");
 Serial.print("http://");
 Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
 Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
 // Check if a client has connected
 WiFiClient client = server.available();
 if (!client) {
   return;
 }

 // Wait until the client sends some data
 Serial.println("new client");
 while(!client.available()){
   delay(1);
 }

 // Read the first line of the request
 String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
 Serial.println(request);
 client.flush();

 // Match the request

 int value = LOW;
 if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1) {
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
   value = HIGH;
 }
 if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1){
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
   value = LOW;
 }



 // Return the response
 client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
 client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
 client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
 client.println("<html>");

 client.print("Led pin is now: ");

 if(value == HIGH) {
   client.print("On");  
 } else {
   client.print("Off");
 }
 client.println("<br><br>");
 client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=ON\">here</a> Turn relay ON<br>");
 client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=OFF\">here</a> Turn relay OFF<br>");
 client.println("</html>");

 delay(1);
 Serial.println("Client disconnected");
 Serial.println("");

}
```

After uploading the code **successfully** and watching the monitor, the light gets turned on and I get the following message:

```
16:02:20.400 -> WiFi connected
16:02:20.425 -> Server started
16:02:20.479 -> Use this URL : http://192.168.100.7/
16:02:41.680 -> new client
16:02:41.680 -> GET / HTTP/1.1
16:02:41.680 -> Client disconnected
```

However, when I turn on or off the relay using the browser, nothing happens:

```
19:38:56.010 -> new client
19:38:56.010 -> GET /LED=ON HTTP/1.1
19:38:56.010 -> Client disconnected
19:38:57.016 -> new client
19:38:57.016 -> GET /LED=OFF HTTP/1.1
19:38:57.063 -> Client disconnected
```

However nothing happens to the light and relay doesn't click.

**a few more notes:**

- I tried in upload the code with relay at high to disconnect the circuit but light is still on
- Wemos Network name appears in my network list
- It doesn't not respond to AT Commands

Comment: did you in Tools select exactly the  "D1 R1"?

Comment: @Juraj  yes the board selected is Wemos D1 R1

Comment: Your code should switch off the lamp when starting up (set the relay pin to LOW), but this is not what you experience. Are you sure you connected the lamp correctly (to COM and NO and not COM and NC)? What happens when you connect an LED (through a 200 to 330 ohm resistor) to Pin 3 instead of the relay?

Comment: The negative side of the LED should be connected to ground.

Comment: @StarCat I replaced the relay with LED with resistor and it just works perfect :)

Comment: So, now you know that the pin switches at the correct time, you have confirmation that your code works correctly and the problem is likely with your hardware. I think the fact that you're trying to switch a 5V relay with a 3.3V device might be the problem (see Duncan C's answer).

Comment: @StarCat I tried to power the 5V Relay from Arduino UNO R3 by attaching VCC and GND to it and keeping the in wired to Wemos D1 R1 D3 pin, but it didn't work either. Any suggestion to resolve the issue with additional Modules.

Comment: The relay likely needs about 5V on the "IN" pin to be able to switch the relay, which it will not get from your Wemos D1 as that is a 3.3V device. If you want to control a relay from your Wemos D1, you need a one that works with 3.3V.

Comment: @StarCat Solved by implementing 2N2222 transistor and 5K resistor. Thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with Wemos Module where it only outputs 3.3V which insufficient to 5V Relay so this can be solved by implementing 2N2222 Transistor as per schematic below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the Wemos D1 R1 a 5V board, or 3.3V? If it's a 3.3V board, that's your problem. Get a 3.3V relay.

(From a little digging it looks like the Wemos is a 3.3V device. If so, that is your problem. Those "digital relays" are available in 5V and 3.3V models. Replace your 5V relay with a 3.3V relay.)

What are the current requirements of the relay, and what is the max current you can draw out of the Wemos? How are you powering the Wemos?

I would say break this into pieces and solve them separately. Put a multimeter (OR an LED with a current limiting resistor) on pin D3 and make sure the pin is turning on and off. If it is, it is a problem with your relay. If it's not, it's a problem with your sketch or your Arduino.

If the pin is turning on and off, try attaching the IN pin on your relay directly to +5V. Does your lightbulb light then?

Comment: The led is working perfect but for the last recommendation by attaching the in pin to +5V, nothing happens except the bulb turning off as soon as I pulled the wire out of D3

Comment: You disconnect the wire from D2 and hook it directly to the +5 (or rather the +3.3v) pin, and the lightbulb does not light? What if you touch that wire to ground? (I'm wondering if you're wired your lightbulb into the normally open (NC) terminal on your relay rather than normally closed (NC).

Comment: @DuncanC I wired it to NC and the same thing no response, however light is off now. BTW, I don't hear any clicks from the relay.

Comment: A 5V relay requires 5 volts to operate. Your Wemos appears to be a 3.3V device. It only puts out 3.3V on it's logic lines. Get a voltmeter and measure the voltage on pin D3 when it is set to HIGH. I bet dollars to doughnuts it's putting out 3.3V. Buy a 3.3V of your digital relay and use that instead (Assuming your Wemos has enough current out of it's regulator to power the relay.